# Telerik MVC Grid focus on first filter field on page load

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, grid, telerik, focus

I am trying to find a way for when the page is initally loaded to set the users cursor and focus on the item_id filter text box.  simular to how to do it for a razor page " @autofocus = "autofocus"" or

```
$(function () {
    $('.focus :input:first').focus();
});
```

I cannot seem to find a working solution to focus on the filter row when a user loads the page.

I am trying to set focus on the 'item_id' filter text box

This is what the column part of the grid looks like.  I have tried to add an event when the grid loads to find the textbox and then set focus but it does not look like anything is exposed.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Portal.Models.Location_Inventory>()
                                    .Name("grid")
                                        .Columns(columns =>
                                        {
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.item_id).Title("Item ID").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains)).UI("focus"));
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.item_desc).Title("Item Desc").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains)));
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.ext_desc).Title("Extended Desc").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains)));
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.vmi_pkg).Title("VMI Pack Size").Filterable(false).Width(125);
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.bin).Title("Bin").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains))).EditorTemplateName("String");
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.qty_issued).Title("Qty to Issue").Filterable(false).EditorTemplateName("Integer").Width(125);                                        
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.qty_on_hand).Title("Qty on Hand").Filterable(false).EditorTemplateName("Integer").Width(125);

                                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if this works for you.

```js
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Portal.Models.Location_Inventory>()
                                    .Name("grid")
                                        .Columns(columns =>
                                        {
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.item_id).Title("Item ID").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains)).UI("focus"));
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.item_desc).Title("Item Desc").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains)));
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.ext_desc).Title("Extended Desc").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains)));
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.vmi_pkg).Title("VMI Pack Size").Filterable(false).Width(125);
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.bin).Title("Bin").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains))).EditorTemplateName("String");
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.qty_issued).Title("Qty to Issue").Filterable(false).EditorTemplateName("Integer").Width(125);                                        
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.qty_on_hand).Title("Qty on Hand").Filterable(false).EditorTemplateName("Integer").Width(125);

                                }).Events(ev => ev
                                            .DataBound("onDataBound")
                                 )
<script>
function onDataBound(arg) {
    $('[data-text-field="item_id"]').focus();
}
</script>
```